# How to migrate an app from the Picasa API to the Google Photos API

Tags: javascript, google-photos, google-photos-api

My company has a software that allow users to print photobooks, canvases and stuff like that, and we also allow people to upload photos from social networks such as Google Photos, last month, the old Picasa API was deprecated and now i have to migrate it to the new google photos API. Does anyone know the easiest way to do so?

Been trying to figure out what I have to do from the Getting started guide from google but haven't been able to integrate it with what I already have from the last picasa api.

Answer (score -1):

The developer documentation for the Picasa Web Albums Data API includes a migration guide: https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/3.0/developers_guide_migration

It walks through the basic differences between the Picasa API and the new Google Photos Library API.

You may also be interested in the [client libraries for the Google Photos Library API](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/client-libraries) that are available for Java and PHP.

If you have any specific questions about the technology or API calls, or if you run into any errors you should post them here as new questions. Don't forget to include as much technical detail as possible. General questions are always difficult to answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time, i'll try to guide myself from this and will ask in a new question later if i need.